# POST message via REST API by reading them via data.csv file & capture responses and validate it in 3 db tables TC passes sometimes and fails sometimes

Tags: sql-server, database, api, rest, karate

I am reading 4 messages from data.csv file (has 1 column called data and 3 rows with message). now I am posting them via rest end point URL. I capture the response which is usually a single string , something like 'GHRGHRH-GSGA'. now I validate if the same response is present in 3 different tables. When I execute it , always the first iteration passes. the next 3 iterations sometimes they pass and sometimes they fail. I tried to add timeout, wait until  or assert, but they haven't helped me. It's not consistently passing .What am I missing here ? I am learning Karate so kind of new here.

table1  has id and payload where I need to verify if response I capture from API == id and payload== data from 1st row .

table 2 has id 2 and message where I need to verify if response I capture from API == id2 and message == data from 1st row .

table 3 has same id 2 where I need to verify if response I capture from API == id2. table 2 and table 3 have same field name .

@parallel=false
Feature: Testing end to end scenario

``
Background:
* url APIurl
* def DbUtils = Java.type('com.api.test.DbUtils')
* def config = karate.call('classpath:karate-config.js')
* def db = new DbUtils(config)

Scenario Outline:  Read  messages from CSV file and POST it via API Request and validate if its present in the database

```
Given url APIurl
And request '<data>'
When method POST
Then status 200
And print response
* def test1 = db.readRows('select id, payload from table1 where id = \'' + response + '\'')
And match test1[0].id == response
And match test1[0].payload == '<data>'
* def test2 = db.readRows('select id2, message from table2 where id2 = \'' + response + '\'' )
And match test2[0].id2 == response
And match test2[0].message == '<data>'
* def test3 = db.readRows('select id2 from table3 where id2 = \'' + response + '\'')
And print test3
And match test3[0].id2 == response



Examples:
  | read('data.csv') |
```

``

I initially thought may be its taking longer to execute the database queries, and tried timeout , wait until, assert etc. but it didn't work. Sometimes this TC passes, but most times it fails.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't think this is something anyone else can help you with, you will have to figure this out on your own. since maybe karate is running the CSV rows in parallel, try to not do that (refer docs for `@parallel=false`) or use a single thread. also refer this answer which may be a better way to manage your loop: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76078957/143475 - a lot depends on how you have implemented that `db.readRows()` java code, it has nothing to do with karate

Comment: Thanks Peter. I am using @parallel=false. Sorry the way I posted my message was incorrect. if you scroll above , I mentioned that in my feature file and background. So I think when I check logs, it fails in the DB execution flow.like if I print test2 or test 3, most of the times it returns empty value. like 10:04:14.127 [print] [
] . but sometimes I get lucky and values get populated.

Comment: I have nothing to add. if you really want someone to look into this you have to follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue